# Angular2 delay inside ForEach

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, settimeout, delay

I have an application in angular2 in which I must reproduce a history of events.

So, when I press the PLAY button, it must start with the first event, stay there for 3 seconds, then go to the next event, stay there for another 3 seconds, then the next, and so on.

The event list is dynamic.

The point is that with a simple `setTimeOut` this does not work and I want to know if there is another way to solve what I need.

I tried this:

```
play() {
  if (this.history !== undefined) {
    this.playMode = true;
    const allEvents = this.history;
    const historyLength = allEvents.length;
    const progressInterval = 100 / historyLength;
    allEvents.forEach(e => {
      console.log(e);
      setTimeout(t => {
        this.progress += progressInterval;
      }, 3000);
    });
  }
}
```

and I need the this.progress variable to show the progrees in a `mat-progress-barr`

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="playMode" strokeWidth="0.5" mode="determinate" [value]="progress" color="accent"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Obviously my code doesn't works as I want.

How can I do that "delay"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a forEach loop you can use it through normal array index notation. Here is an example

```
play() {
  if (this.history !== undefined) {
    this.playMode = true;
    const allEvents = this.history;
    const historyLength = allEvents.length;
    const progressInterval = 100 / historyLength;
    /*allEvents.forEach(e => {
      console.log(e);
      setTimeout(t => {
        this.progress += progressInterval;
      }, 3000);
    });*/

    this.incrementProgress(allEvents, 0, progressInterval);
  }
}

incrementProgress(allEvents: any[], index: number, interval: number): void {
  if (allEvents.length <= 0 || index < 0 || index >= allEvents.length) {
    return;
  }

  this.progress += interval;
  setTimout(() => this.incrementProgress(allEvents, index + 1, interval), 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do what @t8ortotlover said, but it would still not guarantee 3 second delay. It would be close, but not quite.

You should use timer:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

const source = timer(3000);
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => {
    // Do something every 3 seconds
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like all your timeouts are scheduled for the same instant. Try this out:

```
play() {
  if (!this.history) {
    return;
  }

  const allEvents = this.history;
  const historyLength = allEvents.length;
  const progressInterval = 100 / historyLength;
  this.playMode = true;

  allEvents.forEach((event, index) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(event);
      this.progress += progressInterval;
    }, 3000 * index);
  });
}
```

Note that we're now using the index provided by `forEach` to offset the timeouts by 3 seconds. The first one will fire immediately `(3000 * 0 = 0)`. If that is unwanted, you can simply add one to the index `setTimeout(() => {...}, 3000 * (index + 1))`.